# Inertia Vue 3 - Vue component not receiving props

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, vue-props

i want to pass `users` from `Inertia render` to `vue` component:

`routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Dashboard',['users'=> DB::table('users')->get()]);
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
```

i recieve `users` as `props` in my `vue` component:

`resources/Pages/Dashboard.vue`

```
<script setup>
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue";
import { Head } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
defineProps({
    users: {
        type: Array,
    },
});
console.log(users); //error
import Nav from "../Components/Nav.vue";
import Header from "../Components/Header.vue";
import Content from "../Components/Content.vue";
</script>

<template>
    <Head title="Dashboard" />

    <AuthenticatedLayout>
        <template #header>
            <Header />
        </template>

        <template #nav>
            <Nav />
        </template>
        <template #content>
            <Content />
        </template>
    </AuthenticatedLayout>
</template>
```

however Dashboard component doesn't receive users, it gives me error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: users is not defined`, why is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#props-declaration), the properties are returned from the function call.

On a sidenote: always group imports together.

This should work:

```html
<script setup>
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue";
import { Head } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import Nav from "../Components/Nav.vue";
import Header from "../Components/Header.vue";
import Content from "../Components/Content.vue";

const props = defineProps({
    users: {
        type: Array,
    },
});
console.log(props.users);
</script>
```

Comment: doesn't work, same error

Comment: Try adding `, default: []` after `type: Array` - we should be able to rule out a code defect in that way.

Comment: doesn't work, it's like the component doesn't recognize any ```props```

Comment: Also note that it's quite unusual to _use_ defined props inside setup.

My suggestion: change the template to add elements for each user you're expecting (a simple `<div v-for="user in users">a user</div>` should be fine).

If that also fails, I'm afraid I'm quite clueless.

Be sure to remove / comment-out the `console.log` for this test!

Comment: Additionally, maybe mention the entire stack trace of the reference error inside your question - it could be helpful.